Unable to obtain link to download the ADE20k-full dataset
I was trying to register here (https://groups.csail.mit.edu/vision/datasets/ADE20K/) to get the link to download the ADE20k-full dataset but I keep getting the following error: "Fatal error attempting mail, contact your server administrator".
I have tried with different emails... But none of them work!
Is anyone experiencing the same issue?
Thanks!

Seems we're not the only ones.
I got around this by downloading the 2021 version here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sssunyy/ade20k/data
And the 2016 version here: http://sceneparsing.csail.mit.edu/
Based on the conversation I found here, it looks like downloading from the official site gets you the 2021 version, but it's hard to know for sure without access.
